# how to use proxy for HTTP connection on android?

Tags: java, android, http

The usual java way doesnt seem to work - i put in bogus values in there and it still "works", so it seems that android doesnt read those properties.
I also put this info into Settings section of OS (via GUI). 
ANy ideas? Thx.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("http.proxyHost", "190.128.1.69");
    props.put("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two ways to do it.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", <your proxy host name>);
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", <your proxy port>);
```

or

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpHost httpproxy = new HttpHost("<your proxy host>",<your proxy port>);
httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, httpproxy);
```

Comment: Like @Saideira said, the "first way" doesn't seem to work (at least for some people...) - but the "second way" does work for me also.